# Powershell - Use Managed Service Identity to access Azure Data Lake Store

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-data-lake

I have found following tutorial, which explains, how to do it using portal: [Use Managed Service Identity for a Linux VM to access Azure Data Lake Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/tutorial-linux-vm-access-datalake)
I need to replicate actions from `Grant your VM access to Azure Data Lake Store` section but from PowerShell.
Any hints how to achieve that and what cmdlets to use?

Comment: I'm actually not sure, but I do know about MSI. What you are looking for is a command that gives a *service principal* access to the ADLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. You could use [`Set-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datalakestore/set-azurermdatalakestoreitemaclentry?view=azurermps-5.4.0) to do this.

As junnas said, when you enable MSI for a VM, it will create a service principal.

[image]

You could use the following example:

```
$vmname="shui"
$vm=Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$vmname'"
Set-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry -AccountName "shuitest" -Path / -AceType User -Id $vm.ObjectId -Permissions All
```

Comment: It seems you use Windows OS, please check this link  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/tutorial-windows-vm-access-datalake